# Remove columns based on their values in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

How can we remove columns of data frame based on column values? I want to remove all the columns which have either null/'' or zero. Suppose panda dataframe `df` is

```
df['c1']=[1,2,3,3,4]
df['c2']=["a1","a2","a2","a2","a1"]
df['c3']=[1,2,3,3,5]
df['c4']=['','',0,0,0]
df['c5']=[np.nan,np.nan,0,0,0]
print df
```

Output is

```
    c1  c2  c3 c4   c5
 0   1  a1   1     NaN
 1   2  a2   2     NaN
 2   3  a2   3  0  0.0
 3   3  a2   3  0  0.0
 4   4  a1   5  0  0.0
```

I want code to find out columns `c4` and `c5` and remove it.

Comment: Usually at least some effort is required before posting. SO's not a coding service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does the trick for the example dataframe.

```
badvalues = [0, np.nan]
goodcolumns = [n for n in df.columns 
               if not df[n].isin(badvalues).any()]
df = df[goodcolumns]
```

If you have issues with the nan values not working, you can use `isnull`:

```
goodcolumns = [n for n in df.columns
               if not ((df[n] == 0) | df[n].isnull()).any()]
```

Comment: IMO `isin` does not work well with `np.nan` values:
    In [8]: s = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 2])  

   In [9]: s[~s.isin([np.nan])]    
  Out[9]: 
  0    1.0
  1    NaN
  2    2.0
  dtype: float64

Comment: @lazy1: it works for the example dataframe. I've added a method using `isnull` to my answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
>>> cols_to_drop = df.applymap(lambda x: x in [0, np.nan]).any()
>>> cols_to_drop
c1    False
c2    False
c3    False
c4     True
c5     True
dtype: bool
>>> df.drop(df.columns[cols_to_drop], axis=1)
   c1  c2  c3
0   1  a1   1
1   2  a2   2
2   3  a2   3
3   3  a2   3
4   4  a1   5
```